# Node Stripe file upload from request.get body res

Tags: node.js, file, upload, get, stripe-payments

I'm using a Node env where I'm making a request.get to retrieve a file from a url then sending that off to Stripe. I get a 141 error that my file is invalid. There is intermediary step between retrieving the file and sending it off that I am missing but not sure which. I used to use fs.readFileSync for a local file but don't use it anymore since I'm retrieving the file from a server now.

```
Request.get(req.params.url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    Stripe.fileUploads.create({
      purpose: 'identity_document',
      file: {
        data: body, // missing a step before sending it off
        name: 'file.png',
        type: 'application/octet-stream'
      }
    }, function(err, fileUpload) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
        return res.error(err);
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(fileUpload));
    });
    // Continue with your processing here.
  }
});
```

Here is the error I get from Stripe

```
code=141, type=StripeInvalidRequestError, rawType=invalid_request_error, code=undefined, param=file, message=We don't currently support that file type. Try uploading a file with one of the following mimetypes: image/jpeg, image/png, detail=undefined, type=invalid_request_error, message=We don't currently support that file type. Try uploading a file with one of the following mimetypes: image/jpeg, image/png
```

Comment: I guess you need to change your mimetime as, `type:image/png` instead of the present type: `'application/octet-stream'`

Answer (score 0):

Change `file.type` from `application/octet-stream` to `image/png`.